# Adding AntiForgeryToken to non-Ajax Form Submit

Tags: c#, forms, post, antiforgerytoken

I found plenty of examples that demonstrate how to add an `AntiForgeryToken` to the `Ajax` call for POST submit method. My need, as the title suggests, is to submit a form NOT via the `ajax` call. Instead, I'm simply using jQuery `submit()` function.

What I have in my razor view file is as follows (Note: I'm using html string literal because this particular DOM needs to be dynamically attached to a separate element at a later point):

```
var html =
    "<form id='exportPdfForm' action='" + exportUrl + "' method='post'>" +
        "<input type='hidden' id='exportContent'>" +
        "<input type='hidden' id='__RequestVerificationToken' value='@Html.AntiForgeryToken()'>" +
    "</form>";
```

And, obviously, I'm using the following jQuery to submit this form:

```
$("#exportPdfForm").submit();
```

Also, using the DOM Explorer I can see the `AntiForgeryToken` value is properly in place:
[image]

However, when I actually submit the form, I still run into the *`The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present`* error. I checked out several other Q&A's but can't seem to find anything that might shed some light on my problem.

Am I missing something obvious or doing something wrong here?

**EDIT** (Solution)

Assigning the `__RequestVerificationToken` to the `name` attribute will fix it:

```
<input type='hidden' name='__RequestVerificationToken' value='...'>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one turns out to be one of those "How did I miss that...?!" moments. While the above approach is perfectly legitimate, the only problem is that the `__RequestVerificationToken` has to belong to a `name` attribute instead of to an `id` as in my initial example. I tried posting my form with the fix and the problem is now gone.

Obviously this wouldn't have been an issue in the first place if I could just use the `<% Html.AntiForgeryToken(); %>` expression, but this particular case required an unconventional approach for the reason I stated in my initial post. So, I guess this is something to look out for!

Comment: Great solution for those who needs to send a form to a Razor page and get the input values usint OnPost(),thanks!